# Div does not extend to fill the screen vertically

Tags: html, css

I can't for the life of me get the green (content) and the purple (nav) divs to take up the remained of the height space to fill the screen.

I know its simple but obviously i have taken leave of my senses and can't see it!

http://www.bestlincs.co.uk/new/

```css
body
{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#main
{
 height: 100%;
 border:dashed #D82629 1px;
}

#content
{
 
 overflow: hidden;
 width: auto;
 height: 100%;
 background-color:rgba(41, 171, 0, 0.5)
}

#nav
{
 float: right;
 background-color:rgba(41, 0, 226, 0.5);
 width: 250px;
 height: 100%;
}

#footer
{
 position: absolute;
 bottom:0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
 background-color:rgba(41, 171, 226, 0.5)
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
 
    <div id="nav">
        <p>navnavnavnavnavnavnavnav</p>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <p>contentcontent<br>gf dfg dfg dfg dfg df</p>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <p>footerfooter</p>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question itself check here for more info : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What's the matter? The whole screen is filled. What exactly do you want?

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML+CSS, rather than just linking. Also what do you mean by _remaining height space_? Do you mean everything except the blue footer?

Comment: Yes Rhumbori thats correct

Comment: add `height:100%` to your `html` and `body` then calibrate the `height` of `nav`, `content`, `footer` using percentage not pixel, should total of 100%

Comment: Roi - I want the footer to be a set height though

Comment: then you need javascript for the calculation of heights, because viewport is not always the same depending on the hardware.

Comment: I'm confused, all i want is the bottom div to be 250 pixels and the div above to take up the rest of the window

Comment: like here http://jsfiddle.net/DwApF/2/

Comment: if its fine with you to do that, then set the `height` of `nav` and `content` to `100%`.. i may warn you that when the contents gets a little long, it will go beneath the `footer`

Comment: Roi - I have nearly got there but now how do i stop the bottom blue bar from overlapping when you shrink the window ?